# Asp Mvc read multiple appSettings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration

I have to configure a list of values in the web.config of MVC 5 application. 
Is there a way to read multiple `appSettings` values? For example get all that have some prefix.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="mylist_1" value="val1" />
    <add key="mylist_2" value="val2" />
    <add key="mylist_3" value="val3" />
    <add key="mylist_4" value="val4" />

    <add key="otherlist_1" value="val1" />
    <add key="otherlist_2" value="val2" />
    <add key="otherlist_3" value="val3" />
    <add key="otherlist_4" value="val4" />
</appSettings>
```

I have to get `mylist_1` or `otherlist_1`.
The simple option is to put all the values under one key, delimited by some char and split the string in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you all of the settings, you can then filter out the ones you need quite easily from the collection.

```
var keys = ConfigurationManager
    .AppSettings
    .AllKeys
    .Where(k => k.StartsWith("xxx"));

var values = keys
    .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                         (k, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[k]));
```

Now you can see all the keys/values like this:

```
foreach (var kvp in values)
{
    var key = kvp.Key;
    var val = kvp.Value;
}
```

Make sure you have a project reference to `System.Configuration` and a respective `using System.Configuration;` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var mylistValues =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Where(p => p.StartsWith("mylist_")).Select(p => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[p]).ToList();
```